# Why PostgreSQL Server shuts down occasionally?

Tags: postgresql, azure

[image: Restart every time i use PostgreSQL service]

I'm using a Postgresql 9.5 service on Ubuntu on an Azure VM. When I use the service it works perfectly but when I stop using it for a couple of hours it automatically shuts down and the only solution I found is to restart PostgreSQL before using it

I want to prevent the PostgreSQL service from shutting down automatically

Comment: Postgres 9.5 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  anyway. You should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: What does the log file say?

Answer (score -1):

you can adjust the timeout setting to a longer period.

you'll need to modify the Postgresql.conf, typically located at /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf on Ubuntu.

search for the line

```
# - Idle Session Timeout -
#idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0   # in milliseconds, 0 is disabled
```

uncomment the line removing the `#` and save it, and finally restart your server:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Comment: That timeout doesn't shutdown the server, it just severs the idle session.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the server shutting down. Plus: that setting wasn't available in 9.5 to begin with.